# I changed my EC2 instances security group and it no longer works

Tags: amazon-web-services

I changed the security group for port 5000 from 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 to {myip}/32. Now AWS says 1/2 status checks failed, and the server reachability is failing.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add more details - remember we know absolutely nothing about your setup other than what you tell us, so things that are obvious to you, we could only guess. When you say "AWS says", where are you seeing that message? When you say "server reachability", what is failing to reach it? What is running on port 5000? What else do you have set up that's connected in some way to this instance?

Comment: Seems unlikely that it would be related to a security group change.

Answer (score 0):

The Status Check on an Amazon EC2 instance is totally unrelated to Security Groups.

I suggest that you Stop and Start the instance. If it still fails with a Status Check, it would appear that something has changed on the computer itself (eg permissions changed on Operating System files). Again, this is unrelated to Security Groups, which exist totally outside the instance.